# How to enforce 24Hr Format in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I am currently facing an issue in JS where I need to enforce a 24-hour format in each time input but, in MAC only it is showing a 12-hour format. I could not find useful solutions, most of them suggested using a date-picker package but that I don't want to do.
Is there any possible solution to this problem?

Here is the screenshot
[image]

Here is my code

```js
const dateTimeString = (timestamp) => {
  return new Date(timestamp).toISOString().substring(0, 16);
};

function createElement({
  type,
  attributes = {},
  innerText
}) {
  const element = document.createElement(type);
  Object.keys(attributes).forEach((item) => {
    element.setAttribute(item, attributes[item]);
  });
  element.textContent = innerText;
  return element;
}

const extensionForContainer = document.getElementById("extension-container")
const extensionInput = createElement({
  type: 'input',
  attributes: {
    class: 'date-input hidden',
    type: 'datetime-local',
    name: 'newEndsOn',
    id: 'newEndsOn',
    value: dateTimeString(1698196920),
  },
});
extensionForContainer.appendChild(extensionInput);
```

```html
<html>
  <div id="extension-container">
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean *'in MAC only'*? Looks to be browser specific, and based on the user's OS, from the docs: *'the displayed date and time are formatted according to the user's locale as reported by their operating system'*

Comment: Also relevant discussion on an old [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1425218)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends upon the system preferences, you cannot enforce it.